# How to find the row and column position of an array of button

Tags: android

I have created an array of button now on click of each buttons I call onClick method...on that method is it possible to the position of button ie row and column position.. The code I have written is:

Code for crating Array of buttons..

```
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
            LinearLayout rowLayout=null;

            LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);

            //Create Button
            for (i = 0; i<6; i++) 
            {
                rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
                layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
                for(j=0;j<7;j++)
                {
                    pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);
                    rowLayout.addView(pBtnDay[i][j],param); 

                    pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(this); 
                }
            }
            return true;
```

code for onClick Method

```
            Button b = (Button)view;
            txtDate.setText(b.getText());
            boolean bStartDate=false;
```

now in onclick method i can getText of each button by using `Button b=(Button)view`..so is it possible to get the row and column positions..of that particular button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand row and column is just a your concept since LinearLayout does not provide a Table like objects disposition or a row/column lookup method.

You can just use `Button.setTag()` and save your `j` and `x` values:

```
 class ButtonPosition {
     int x,y;
     public ButtonPosition(int x,int y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }
}


......
for(j=0;j<7;j++){
     pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);
     rowLayout.addView(pBtnDay[i][j],param); 
     pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
     //Save the position
     pBtnDay[i][j].setTag(new ButtonPosition(i,j));
}
```

Position lookup into the `onClick` method

```
.....
 Button b = (Button)view;
 ButtonPosition p = (ButtonPosition)b.getTag();
 .....
```

Comment: ButtonPosition p = (ButtonPosition).getTag();show error in this line..error is create constant ButtonPosition

Comment: i am able to save the position of buttons but how can i retrieve this positons on click of each button..means suppose i click on button having position 0,0 then i get the position as 0 0;

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a syntax error before: It should be: `ButtonPosition p = (ButtonPosition)b.getTag();`